# Shopify display image thumbnails for variant options

Tags: shopify

I am so stuck trying to find an answer for this and I can't find it anywhere. Yet I have seen it done online. Basically all I want to do is have images show instead of the text.

Available finishes: White, Antique, Cinnamon

And instead of the text, they can select an image representing each color.

Example: [http://www.amazon.com/Sundesa-BB28-MC01-BlenderBottle%C2%AE-Classic-28-ounce/dp/B0018G4ZEW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363033335&sr=8-1&keywords=blender+bottle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0018G4ZEW)

I DO NOT need the image to change as you select a color. I just need the color images to show...

Answer (score 1):

You've probably found the answer by now, but are you looking for something like this? It worked well for us. http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/add-color-swatches-to-your-products

Answer (score 0):

Inside the theme, shopify usually create a form with HTML tag option. Using liquid (Shopify language you use on the front end) you may add HTML tag img (image). You could load the own product image (probably you need to set the order properly matching variants with images). Another option is to load an image inside the theme assets, but you would have to upload it one by one. Hope it may give any idea...